# MSTest for C# project targeting .Net version 5?

Tags: mstest, .net-5

I have a .Net desktop project that targets .net V5. I added a MSTest project to write some tests but the highest version of .Net that I can target seems to be 4.8. How do I target .net 5.0 on my testing project? My project that I need to test references .Net 5.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a .net core test project.

.net 5.0 is not .net framework. Since you added a framework project, it only allows you to choose up to 4.8 which is the latest .net framework version.

You can find a guide for the console version creation here: [create test project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest#create-the-test-project)

Or follow the [visual studio guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/create-a-unit-test-project?view=vs-2022#to-create-a-unit-test-project)